# MS Access Date Picker works on first record (save, update etc.), but after submit doesn't fill textbox on other records

Tags: ms-access, textbox, datepicker, vba, ms-access-2013

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I have an interesting problem. When I open my access program and use the date picker (its a date field textbox, bound, short date format) I can update an existing record using the date picker (date selected, fills the textbox that is bound to the date field in the DB)... but ONLY add ONCE. This only happens in one form, which is a data-entry form with no edits, deletions etc.

I'm totally flabbergasted, after saving the record (and I've played around with changing the way it saves the record, from dirty = false and runcommand acccmdsaverecord), I've checked every format option - and I'm really pulling my hair out! This is an enabled and unlocked textbox

The date picker does show, and lets me select a date from the calendar, but then it does not get carried over into the textbox and likewise to the table.

It goes across all forms as well. I've tried removing code, saving, and re-pasting - this did not solve the problem.

Have any of you experienced this? And do any of you have an idea of how to troubleshoot this?

Thank you so much!

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue has to do with the dialog msgbox. When a record is saved successfully I had set to have a message box be displayed that said "Success". Despite having used the exact same code in other applications, by commenting this out the problem is not replicated.

There must be something linked between MsgBox and the date picker.

Comment: What event did you use to have the Msgbox pop up?

Comment: @newd Apologies for the late reply. The full code that is executed (its a call procedure) is as follows: `If CurrentProject.AllForms("TaskAdd").IsLoaded Then
MsgBox ("Success" & vbCrLf & "Task Number: " & Forms!TaskAdd!tboTaskNumber & " has been assigned.")
Else
MsgBox ("Success")
End If
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Service_Landing"
DoCmd.Requery`   ---- I apologize also I appear to not know how to return on a comment.

Comment: This is a known access bug. closing and marking as answered.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is coming a couple years too late - but as I searched for a resolution - I never found it online.  Hopefully this will help someone else:

To make the date picker portion usable, you must go to the Form the text box sits on and change the property Allow Edits (Data Tab) to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

@newd Apologies for the late reply. The full code that is executed (its a call procedure) is as follows:

`If CurrentProject.AllForms("TaskAdd").IsLoaded Then 
MsgBox ("Success" & vbCrLf & "Task Number: " & Forms!TaskAdd!tboTaskNumber & " has been assigned.") 
Else 
MsgBox ("Success") 
End If 
DoCmd.Close 
DoCmd.OpenForm "Service_Landing" 
DoCmd.Requery`